# AngularJS: store all previous ng-focus events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, event-handling

I have a panel with ng-focus objects:

```
            <div style="font: 30pt bold; color: #000; text-align: center; ">Add Elements:</div>
            <div id="arrow" class="Icon" style="margin-top: 10%; height: 140px;" tabindex="0" merch-draggable="draggable" ng-focus="focusHandler($event)">
                <img id="arrow" width="150" height="30" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icon, 'img/arrow.png')}"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="box" ng-focus="focusHandler($event)" class="Icon" tabindex="0" style="height: 140px;" merch-draggable="draggable">
                <img id="box" width="120" height="80" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icon, 'img/box.png')}"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="line" ng-focus="focusHandler($event)" class="Icon" tabindex="0" style="height: 140px;" merch-draggable="draggable">
                <img id="line" width="150" height="50" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icon, 'img/line.png')}"></img>
            </div>
```

...and focus handler function in my app controller:

```
$scope.focusHandler = function focusHandler(ev) {
    console.log('> handler element id: ' + ev.srcElement.id);
    ev = (ev) ? ev : ((window.event) ? window.event : null);
    if(ev) {
        var getID = (ev.target) ? ev.target : event.srcElement;
        console.log('> getID: ' + getID.id);
        FocusService.focusCanvas(getID.id);
    }
}
```

in this handler i get type of object which i want to draw in canvas (arrow, line etc) and send in service FocusService, function focusCanvas (with handlers mouse events):

```
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            angular
                .module('MyApp')
                .service('FocusService', FocusService);

            function FocusService() {
                var service = {
                    focusCanvas: focusCanvas
                };

                return service;

                function focusCanvas(objType) {

                        var circle, isDown, origXX, origYY, line, box, arrow, text, question;
                        activeCanvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
                        activeCanvas.selection = false;

                        activeCanvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){...}
                        activeCanvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){...}
......
```

and if i, for example, at first click arrow in panel, then line, and after that draw in canvas: are drawn these two elements together.

```
 > handler element id: arrow //log from handler on arrow click
 > getID: arrow

 > handler element id: box  //log from handler on arrow click
 > getID: box
```

then one click on canvas, and get log from focusCanvas activeCanvas.on('mouse:down') {console.log(objType);...}

```
arrow
box
```

event mouse down execute twice for arrow and box, but actual object only box.
what is it? where i made a mistake? sorry for my Engl and thanks for your answers ) [Drawn two obj together example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgC0N.png)